# Raspberry Ad-hoc U Broadcasting

Tags: java, linux, network-programming, raspberry-pi, adhoc

I program some ad-hoc application on Raspberry PI. I connect PI and my laptop with ad-hoc network and code a little program to test this network. It seem to work if I send a unicast packet between laptop and Raspberry PI via ad-hoc network but I found some weird problem when I send broadcast packet from Raspberry PI to my laptop. The packet wasn't sent from Raspberry PI (I used wireshark to capture packets) However, if I send a broadcast packet from laptop to Raspberry PI, the PI can receive that packet. Moreover If I send a broadcast packet from PI to laptop on local network it work perfectly. I don't know why. Could you please give me some suggestion

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"AdhocPI"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: 02:11:87:10:D7:41
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=2/100  Signal level=2/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

This is my ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:b8:30:ad
          inet addr:169.254.98.20  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22291 errors:24 dropped:12 overruns:0 frame:12
          TX packets:8305 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2187504 (2.0 MiB)  TX bytes:1274782 (1.2 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:24095 (23.5 KiB)  TX bytes:24095 (23.5 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:80:12:e7
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1589 errors:0 dropped:1160 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:604922 (590.7 KiB)  TX bytes:4714 (4.6 KiB)
```

This is my Java Program to listen a packet

```
public class UDPServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DatagramSocket aSocket = null;
        Message replyMsg =  new Message(999,"reply");
        System.out.println("UDPServer");
        try {
            aSocket = new DatagramSocket(6669);
            aSocket.setBroadcast(true);

            while (true) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
                DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer,
                        buffer.length);
                aSocket.receive(request);
                Message msgReq = null;
                try {
                    msgReq = (Message)Serializer.deserialize(request.getData());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Send back to: "+request.getAddress()+ " port "+request.getPort());

                byte[]replyBytes = Serializer.serialize(replyMsg); 
                DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(replyBytes,
                        replyBytes.length, request.getAddress(),
                        request.getPort());
                aSocket.send(reply);

                System.out.println("Receive Msg : "+ msgReq.show());
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (aSocket != null)
                aSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Java Program to send a broadcast packet

```
public class UDPClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DatagramSocket aSocket = null;
        try {
            //System.out.println("UDPClient " +getBroadcast().toString());
            aSocket = new DatagramSocket(5008);
            Message msgOb = new Message(1, "Hello");
            byte[] m = Serializer.serialize(msgOb);
            InetAddress aHost = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.255");

            int serverPort = 6669;
            System.out.println("Send data to: "+aHost.getHostAddress()+" Port "+serverPort);
            DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(m, m.length,
                    aHost, serverPort);

            aSocket.setBroadcast(true);
            System.out.println("Broadcast: "+aSocket.getBroadcast());
            aSocket.send(request);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[3000];
            DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            aSocket.receive(reply);
            Message msgRep = null;
            try {
                msgRep = (Message)Serializer.deserialize(reply.getData());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Reply: " + msgRep.show());

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (aSocket != null)aSocket.close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on Wifi-adapter. Just change wifi-adapter which has a driver to support ad-hoc mode. It'll work perfectly.